# Java spring error: It is not working even i đid exactly everything the teacher said

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, java-platform-module-system

```
package springdemo4;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class HelloSpringApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Coach theCoach = context.getBean("myCoach",Coach.class);
        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyFortune());
        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
        context.close();

    }

}
```

I ran it, then it said:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\ngoch\eclipse-workspace\springdemo4\libs\spring-context-indexer-5.1.9.RELEASE-sources.jar
>   Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.springframework.context.index.processor.CandidateComponentsIndexer not in module

Please,help

Comment: Looks like your package named `springdemo4` was not being called correctly.

Comment: what version of Java are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to derive module descriptor: Provider {class X} not in module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682417/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-provider-class-x-not-in-module)

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue with Eclipse IDE. I mistakenly added the spring jar files under Modulepath. It should be under Classpath (Properties > Java Build Path > Classpath > addJARs ).

Answer (score 10):

You need to add the libraries under classpath and not under modulepath.

[image: Eclipse IDE]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Spring libraries should be under classpath

Answer (score 2):

Below steps worked for me:
Go to project properties -> Libraries -> add your user libraries under classpath. Remove your librarey reference from Modulepath.

[Project properties from eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgO7l.png)