# HtmlUnit - Unable to derive module descriptor for xalan-2.7.2.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, htmlunit, serviceloader

I am new to HtmlUnit, and really anything outside of the standard java library, and I am getting this error when I try to compile a simple program to print the contents of a webpage.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /Users/***/eclipse-workspace/Research/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module
```

It seems to be an issue with a dependency of a dependency of HtmlUnit, but I have downloaded all of the necessary dependencies and created a reference library for my project. I tried re-downloading xalan individually but the same issue occurred.

I am using Eclipse 4.15.0, the latest java version and jdk, and I wrote this code to test if I set up HtmlUnit correctly.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class cccbdbParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://cccbdb.nist.gov/expgeom1x.asp");
        String pageContent = page.asText();
        System.out.println(pageContent);

    }

}
```

Any advice on how to fix this issue? I haven't been able to find any documentation about this exception in HtmlUnit, it seems to work fine for others.

Edit: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54682966/13521721 describes where the issue comes from, but not how to solve it. Within the JAR for the module `xalan` version 2.7.2, the provider class isn't packaged within the dependency. (The package `org.apache` does not continue to have the package `bfs` and class `BSFManager`, causing the exception). Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: How are you including the dependencies?

Comment: @ronnyfm I created a folder to include the jar file dependencies in my java project in Eclipse and then configured the build path to add all of them as a referenced library