# Selenium: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\Zest1\Desktop\ex01\selenium\standalone\xalan-2.7.2.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module
```

I am using java eclipse, JDK 12 & selenium 4.0.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 11 Unable to derive module descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682417/java-11-unable-to-derive-module-descriptor)