# Module commons.math3 not found using jdeps

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system, module-info, jdeps

I'm using JDEPS to list the dependencies of libraries to ensure they are satisfied.

I've recently upgraded from Apache POI v4.1.1 to v5.0.0, where [JigSaw modules were added](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64411).

Previously, the following command would output the dependencies:

```
jdeps --multi-release 11 poi-scratchpad-4.1.1.jar
```

But now using v5.0.0, I'm getting:

```
jdeps.exe --multi-release 11 poi-scratchpad-5.0.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module commons.math3 not found, required by org.apache.poi.scratchpad
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:894)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:191)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:140)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:422)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:256)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration$Builder.build(JdepsConfiguration.java:564)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.buildConfig(JdepsTask.java:603)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:557)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:533)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

I have the `commons-math3` library, but even when I include it via the `-classpath` argument, I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using `--module-path` instead of the `-classpath` option for the module to be resolved for `commons-math3-3.6.1.jar` should work for you.

In practice, you can detail all the dependencies into a single folder for simplicity and then treat that as modulepath such as following:

[image]

In the above image, I have created a `dependencies` folder that includes the `.jar`s for all dependent libraries for `poi-scratchpad`. Further executing the following command from the same directory works:

```
jdeps --module-path dependencies poi-scratchpad-5.0.0.jar
```

Comment: thankyou, if I try the ``--module-path`` I get a different error, which is... something?
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for batik-script-1.13.jar"

Comment: Currently, it's not possible to derive the automatic module name from certain artifacts for example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9). For those specifically, you can still choose to keep them on the `--class-path` and use both the properties (modulepath and classpath).

Comment: @Jakg for your specific case, it's also worth reading a case when provider classes are not found resulting in unable to derive the automatic module name, as detailed in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682417/java-11-unable-to-derive-module-descriptor)

Comment: do you have an example of mixing the module-path and classpath arguments using the POI dependencies? For me it only gives an error.

Comment: My current thought is that it's a problem wit the batik library - when I update to a newer version, I get a different error regarding another libraries module name. But I'm unsure of what the error is, or how I can fix it in someone else's dependency.