# porting maven project from jdk 8 to higher

Tags: java, maven, java-11, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I am almost there :)
Fixed several issues:

1. Lombok "val" does not work ok in all cases for JDK 11+ -- changed to use "final var" instead
2. AspectJ compiler (ajc) does not recognize source level 16, only 14 -- any workaround for this?
3. Findbugs does not support JDKs beyond 8 -- changed to Spotbugs

Still... I am getting this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-module ---
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from json-path-assert-2.5.0.jar: json.path.assert: Invalid module name: 'assert' is not a Java identifier
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from xalan-2.7.2.jar: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from java-8-matchers-1.9.jar: java.8.matchers: Invalid module name: '8' is not a Java identifier
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] module not found: org.openqa.selenium.core
[ERROR] module not found: httpcore
[ERROR] module not found: httpclient
[INFO] 3 errors
```

Any suggestion(s)?

Comment: 1. Related to `json-path-assert`, you would expect [these changes](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/pull/602) to get merged and released as a long term fix. 2. Related to `xalan` you could refer to [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54682966/1746118), but looking for a well maintained alternate library should be the way forward. 3. Seems like, you have already [reported this](https://github.com/mrwilson/java-8-matchers/issues/20) to the authors. The fix could be very similar to (1) for this as well.

Comment: also opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MCOMPILER/issues/MCOMPILER-464

Comment: That's not a compiler plugin issue. Even if you were to execute `--describe-module` with JDK's `jar` tool for each of these artifacts individually, you would find the same error. It's just the way that the automatic module names are derived by Java and the compiler plugin on top of it is doing its part correctly so far. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9) might be helpful to understand.